# fusion table insert or update from javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, node.js, couchdb, google-fusion-tables

My purpose is to plot data from fusiontable into google map using FusionTablesLayer and to insert or update the fusion table with user created information from map.
I am not able to locate how can I do that from javascript. Is not it possible ?

In case I can not insert or update a fusion table using javascript, what are the other alternatives available ?

I was going through CouchDB with node.js and this appears to be a good alternative. Any expert advise is most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

[Fusion tables have an API](http://code.google.com/apis/fusiontables/docs/developers_guide.html)

Comment: I had seen that earlier and I see that there is a mention about "In addition, no matter what permissions you have, you can insert rows and delete rows only in base tables or views, not merged tables.". But I am not able to locate any example that shows me how to do it. treat this as a beginner question please.

Comment: For example, to select rows we use,
var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
      select: 'Address',
      from: tableid
    },
    map: map
  });
Can we similarly use
query: {
      insert: 'Address',
      table: tableid,
    }

Answer (score 1):

Since authentication is required for inserts and updates to Fusion Tables, it's not super easy to do this through JavaScript alone. It *might* be possible using a JavaScript OAuth library. I haven't tested this approach, but in theory it could work.